# Certificate Used for Azure App Registration

Tags: azure, certificate-authority

We need to create an Azure Application registration for an application which is only being run internally. The requirements are that it uses certificate authentication and we can't use Self Signed.

I have been referring the the document below for the app registration:

[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal][1]

My question is should we use a certificate purchased from an external CA or one issued by the company's pki? If the internal option what kind of certificate should be issued and how do we go about issuing it.

I am not overly familiar with issuing certificates from the internal CA, but I have access to the certificate templates and one of the issuing servers. If someone could point me in the right direction to some instructions then that would be good as I have been looking online and not quite getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of what certificate to use is really up to you, you just need to ensure  you keep it safe.
Given that this certificate is solely used for authentication, and not for providing https then there is not a requirement to use a cert from an external CA, but you can if you want. A cert from an internal CA will work just as well, so long as you can get this certificate installed on the machines that need to use your service principal.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to create a new certificate template and then request a certificate? Then do I need to deploy that certificate through a GPO?

Comment: This all really comes down to how your organisation deals with certificates, not really something I can answer. As far as Azure goes, you need 2 files, a .cer file with the public key which you upload to Azure AD, and a PFX (or similar) file with the private key that you install on the machines you want to use the service principal. How you get these is really down to your own policies.

Comment: I created a certificate template based on a template and was able to request that certificate on the server and then export the private and public keys. The script needs to use CSP as opposed to CNG though. I'm not sure how I get that kind of certificate. Do I create a new template based from the code signing one and import that?